# Accessing multi partition USB hard drive on MacOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, ntfs

I'm having problem accessing a **healthy** USB hard drive on MacOS. The HD is specially partitioned to have

1. EFI
2. 5T ExFat

`diskutil list` output

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨LaCie⁩                   5.0 TB     disk2s2
```

On MacOS, I can see it's detected through `dmesg` but no mounting happens.

[correction] Initially I thought I had NTFS on the drive so I installed Paragon free trial.

*I then downloaded Paragon NTFS and still nothing happens. Paragon doesn't even recognize the drive.*

The drive is perfectly fine as it works with other systems (Windows, Linux).

How can I read it from MacOS?

Comment: post the results of `diskutil list` - The Mac should be able to read & mount the NTFS volumes natively. Paragon is only needed to enable write. I'm not certain about native ExtFS support. I know Mac can't write it natively, but I'm not sure if it can mount or read it. Paragon also make an ExtFS enabler. I'd try the demo, just in case. That neither the Mac nor Paragon can mount it hints at something deeper...

Comment: Try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293390/macos-cant-mount-exfat-external-drive or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381278/how-to-mount-ext4-disk-on-10-15 depending on which it actually is.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the link. `kill fsck` worked

Comment: @Tetsujin If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an oblique reference to [Ask Different - macOS: Can't mount exFAT External Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293390/macos-cant-mount-exfat-external-drive) try killing `fsck` as that might be stuck.

```
sudo pkill -f fsck
```